# Is there an accepted method for finding out why a flag was declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged a question for being off-topic (too many possible answers). It got declined. I now see the question has been put on hold for having too many possible answers.

I feel my flag was valid, but I have no means to refute the declined flag. What's the best way to find out why my flag was declined? It seems a good number of people ask why for their specific flag as a question here, but that doesn't seem like the best way to go about it.

Is there a documented method for me to ask why a flag was declined?
Asking for reasons for a specific flag as a question here seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: What was the decline reason for your flag?  That's probably the best place to find out why it was declined.

Comment: Can you include a link to the post you flagged?

Comment: @Servy I see no reason given for why the flag was declined.

Comment: @bluefeet I flagged this question as off-topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175759/use-javascript-and-ajax-to-retrieve-an-image-from-html-input-tag-and-pass-it-to The question is now on hold, but my flag was declined.

Comment: @Relequestual The question is closed for being too broad.  It's not off topic.  That said, if you actually flagged for closure then the flag wouldn't be declined at all; it wouldn't even be seen by a mod.  It would go to the close queue, and be *disputed* if the queue didn't agree with the flag.

Comment: I thought "off-topic" was the correft flag for when the question is too broad?

Comment: @Servy: In this case it was indeed a flag for closure. Apparently those can be declined by review now, which explains the lack of a decline message.

Comment: @Relequestual No.  "Too Broad" is the correct flag for when a question is too broad.  "Off Topic" is the correct flag for when a question is off topic.

Comment: @Servy ... that is odd... I didn't see that flagging option. I'm sure sometimes the flagging options are limited when I'm reviewing questions in the review queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asking why a flag was declined**

Coming here to Meta is the appropriate action whenever you run across something you don't quite understand. Always search for duplicate first, though. Recommend closure flags have been discussed many times, and you can usually find an answer to your questions about them.

**Your specific case**

You cast a recommend closure flag. Those are only *ever* handled automatically by the system.

A recommend closure flag will be marked as helpful if:

- A user with full vote to close privileges votes to close the question with the same reason you chose (regardless of whether the question is closed).
- The question gets closed while your flag is still active.

A recommend closure flag will be marked as declined if:

- Three people choose the Leave Open option in review while your flag is still active.

Unfortunately for you, [three people did choose to leave it open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6864721) and since no one had chosen "off-topic" as their close reason (and it did have four votes to close at that moment in time), your flag never got dismissed as helpful before that. The third Leave Open action completed review and declined any remaining recommend closure flags on that question.

Comment: I'll have to read that a few times to fully understand, but thanks =] In the case of automated declining, could not the reason also be given if it can be logically defined?

Comment: There is a feature request to [have it link to the review task that declined it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/community-declined-close-vote-flags-should-point-to-the-review-that-declined-the).