# When are flags disputed, and when are they declined by review?

Tags: support, declined-flags, disputed-flags

Coming from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361549/declined-too-broad-flag) question (which I brought up because I thought a moderator had declined my flag, but was apparently declined by fellow reviewers) I've been trying to find where is it documented what the flag resolution means and how to determine how exactly did it come about.

I've seen a few questions about it:

1. [Declined and disputed flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356774/declined-and-disputed-flags)
2. [What is the difference between declined, disputed and aged away?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/what-is-the-difference-between-declined-disputed-and-aged-away)
3. [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags) (the alleged dupe, but which claims that declined flags are so because a diamond mod declined them, and that is not the case here)
4. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511/348149

(etc)

But in all cases the conclusion seem to be the same:

- Disputed come from community
- Declined come from a diamond moderator.

Which at first glance seems to contradict [what happened here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903376/wordpress-on-subdomain-with-laravel-as-frontend):
[image: flag history]

Flag resolution shows as "declined", albeit apparently the rejection came up on review with votes to close according to the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47903376/timeline#review_18309340) which contradict the details in [this meta.se answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141400) found by @Sebastian-proske:

> if the review is completed without any user casting a close vote the flag is declined

And [the relevant page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) in the help-center doesn't say anything about this, at least that I could find.

More digging up by @Tensibai brought up this ([Declined unclear-flag, later post put on hold as offtopic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288082/1426539)), and a comment on it by Brad Larson that says that:

> it was declined by the system after three reviewers voted to leave that question open

Which doesn't change the core of this question: Can we have an updated explanation on what flag resolution messages means today?

Even in the case nothing changed, finding the exact meaning for this messages seems to be a little harder than it should. Maybe we can put all the information in the same place for future reference?

Comment: First comment on your 'uber-meta' link brings [this meta.so question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288082/declined-unclear-flag-later-post-put-on-hold-as-offtopic#comment165758_288082) which let me think the rule has changed somewhere and is 'if the review is closed by 3 leave open, decline the flag, irrespective if there's close votes in review or not'. I'm tempted to say it's a bug...

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai! Maybe it's a bug, maybe it is simply that documentation is lacking. Not complaining about the flag in particular, but would be nice to have and updated and authoritative answer about how this works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags)

Comment: @gnat, I don't mind the flag. But I mention that question specifically, and I do not think it answers this question. At least not fully. I've got a "declined" flag which wasn't declined by a mod, which is what that answer says.

Comment: @gnat It you want to add a comprehensive answer there, this one could be closed as a dupe of that one.

Comment: To close voters as duplicate: what in any of the answers over there explain a close flag being **declined** and not **disputed** ? The question already state this clearly so I assume it is muscle habit ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll break this down into classes of flags, because they are all handled in a slightly different way:

**Comment flags**

These can only be marked as helpful (the comment was deleted, edited, or the post it was on was deleted) or declined (the comment was left as-is).

**Spam / offensive flags**

These can be marked as helpful (deletion by moderator or accumulating sufficient flags from the community), declined by a moderator, or disputed. The disputed state comes from a special moderator action that clears spam / offensive flags from a post, and can be applied retroactively even after a flag has been accepted or declined.

**Close flags**

These aren't handled by moderators, and can be marked as helpful, declined, or disputed as a result of review. If reviewers in the Close Votes review queue agree with your flag and close a post, the flag is marked helpful. If triage reviewers mark the post as "Looks OK" or "Needs Editing", the flag is disputed. (Reference: [the FAQ answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/135615)) The flag will be declined if three reviewers in the Close Votes queue mark a post as "Leave Open". (Reference: [animuson's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284872/19679))

**Not an answer / very low quality flags**

Some of these flags are handled by moderators, and some by community review. They can be marked as helpful, declined, or disputed. They are marked as helpful when a moderator or users delete a post, or when a post has been edited in review. Moderators can decline these flags, but a reason must be provided for the decline. If you see one of these flags declined without a reason, that was the result of a sufficient number of "Looks OK" votes in review. Moderators cannot dispute these flags, but review can via a mix of "Looks OK" and delete votes.

**Other classes of flags**

Remaining flags are handled by moderators, and can only be marked as helpful or declined with a reason. Moderators can't dispute these flags.

I think I've listed the appropriate cases above, but the review thresholds do change regularly, so exact cases may or may not still be valid.

Comment: Can you expand on 'some of these flags are handled by moderators, and some by community review'? and state why this is so?

Comment: The crazy VLQ flag is also marked helpful if post is edited by OP or other user even outside review (but with -1 vote).

Comment: @EJP - As soon as a post is flagged as "very low quality" or "not an answer", it enters community review. For questions, that's Triage, and for answers that's Low Quality Posts. If a post survives for an hour in those queues, it also appears in the moderator flag queue. Depending on the size of the moderator flag queue and the number of flags on a post, we may act on that flag right away or let it sit. The post remains in community review, so it can still be handled by the community even after it appears in our queue.

Comment: Shog9 has stats from 2016 on who handled what flags in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340865/19679). Changes in the top bar led to some review issues earlier this year, so I don't know if the numbers were the same for 2017.

Comment: I'm also confused because a couple of my "not an answer" flags where deemed "helpful", but the answer was not deleted or edited after my flag. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43832155/timeline . Why was the flag marked helpful in this case?

Comment: @yivi - If a post has a positive score and review votes to delete it, the flags are marked as helpful and a system-generated "Post has a good score but received delete votes" flag is raised for moderators to review. We then go through and review each of these, both to prevent good posts from being deleted by bad reviews and to catch things like voting fraud propping up bad answers. Those posts will all be eventually reviewed by a moderator.

Comment: I see that there are more than a few exceptions and pathways for these flags... Thanks a lot for the lengthy explanation. The more we understand the system, the more we trust it; and the more likely we are going to continue flagging away. :)